# Herokuにデプロイできなくなりました

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Ruby on Railsを使ってアプリを開発していた際にgithubを通してHerokuにデプロイしていたのですが，ある時誤まってherokuのappを消してしまいました．
そこで新しくappを作り直し，git remote set-url heroku URL を打ち込んでpush先を変えてgit push heroku master を打ち込んだら以下のようなエラーメッセージが出ました．

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
(base) mbp:hello hoge$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 87, done.
Counting objects: 100% (87/87), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (72/72), done.
Writing objects: 100% (87/87), 22.64 KiB | 2.26 MiB/s, done.
Total 87 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:             Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.5
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
省略
remote:        * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
remote:          https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
remote:        
remote:        Bundle completed (51.26s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed:
remote:  !     Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /tmp/build_cf0cee9dff2cef20e79c0cb16f784873/Gemfile.lock.
remote:  !     To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
remote:  !     To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`
remote:  !     Checked in 'GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0', execute `gem env` for more information
remote:  !     
remote:  !     To install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '2.0.1'`
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed:
remote: Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /tmp/build_cf0cee9dff2cef20e79c0cb16f784873/Gemfile.lock.
remote: To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
remote: To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`
remote: Checked in 'GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0', execute `gem env` for more information
remote: 
remote: To install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '2.0.1'`
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:866:in `rake'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
省略
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:134:in `log'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in `block in <main>'
省略
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !    Push rejected to shrouded-ocean-42963.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/shrouded-ocean-42963.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/shrouded-ocean-42963.git'
```

#### 試したこと

仕方ないので，新しくプロジェクトを書き直して新しいgitのリポジトリからherokuにデプロイしようとしても再び**同じようなエラー**が出ました．
さらに，herokuのアカウントも作り直して，rails newしたばかりのプロジェクトをherokuにあげるという誰がやってもデプロイできるという状況でも**同じエラー**が出ます

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/198021

Answer (score 1):

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
```

となっているので、heroku上ではbundler 2.0.2がインストールされているようです。そのあとのログで

```
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed:
remote:  !     Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /tmp/build_cf0cee9dff2cef20e79c0cb16f784873/Gemfile.lock.
remote:  !     To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
remote:  !     To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`
remote:  !     Checked in 'GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0', execute `gem env` for more information
remote:  !     
remote:  !     To install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '2.0.1'`
```

となっているので、ローカルではbundler 2.0.1を利用しているようですね。なので

- ローカルでbundler 2.0.2をインストール
- bundle install

としたものをherokuにデプロイするとうまくいきそうです